# How to edit the Configurations of a Helm Chart?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, kubernetes-helm, autoscaling

Hi everyone,

I have deployed a Kubernetes cluster based on kubeadm and for the purpose of performing HorizontalPodAutoscaling based on the Custom Metrics, I have deployed prometheus-adpater through Helm.

Now, i want to edit the configuration for prometheus-adpater and because i am new to Helm, i don't know how to do this. So could you guid me how to edit the deployed helm charts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to customize an installed chart. Please use this guide [Customizing the Chart Before Installing](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing).

The key parts:

> There are two ways to pass configuration data during install:
>
> - `--values` (or `-f`): Specify a YAML file with overrides. This can be specified multiple times and the rightmost file will take precedence
> - `--set name=value`: Specify overrides on the command line

Comment: The question is not about passing configuration values during installation. It's about updating configuration values after the installation has already occurred. Please update your answer to reflect what should be done post-installation.

Answer (score 18):

I guess [helm upgrade](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-upgrade) is that are you looking for.

> This command upgrades a release to a specified version of a chart and/or updates chart values.

So if you have deployed prometheus-adapter, you can use command [helm fetch](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-fetch)

> Download a chart from a repository and (optionally) unpack it in local directory

You will have all yamls, you can edit them and upgrade your current deployed chart via helm upgrade

I found an [example](https://dzone.com/articles/create-install-upgrade-rollback-a-helm-chart-part), which should explain it to you more precisely.

Comment: @zainali Hi zain, if that answer was helpfull please accept,upvote it please.

Comment: I gave the upvote but it is not counted because my rating is below 15

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple more ways to customize a Helm Chart values:

You may create a file with defined config and then `helm install my-app [chart] -f /path/to/myconfig.yaml`

As an example for a config file, please refer, for example, to [redis](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/redis/values.yaml) one.

The second one is to check for the files the `helm repo add` or `helm repo update` create. You may check with `helm env` the variable `HELM_REPOSITORY_CACHE` that shows where those files are.

Untar the chart and look for the values config file or even go to the Kubernetes manifests `/templates` for a more in-depth customization. Then, install the chart.